# Use different json keys for marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: go

**What do I have:** two structs for some kind of API

```golang
type BaseUser struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"user_id"`
    Name  string `json:"user_name"`
    Email string `json:"user_email"`
}
```

and

```golang
type UserWithAddress struct {
    BaseUser
    Postal string `json:"user_postal"`
    City   string `json:"user_city"`
    Street string `json:"user_street"`
}
```

**What do I want to do:** convert json keys from snake_case to camelCase.
Lets say, this is a request body

```
{
    "user_id": 123,
    "user_name": "test",
    "user_email": "test@mail.com",
    "user_postal": "12312",
    "user_city": "city",
    "user_street": "street"
}
```

So as a result, after some kind of transformation, I'd like to have this output

```
{
    "userId": 123,
    "userName": "test",
    "userEmail": "test@mail.com",
    "userPostal": "12312",
    "userCity": "city",
    "userStreet": "street"
}
```

**How do I handle this at the moment:** I made another two structs with camelCase `json` tag

```golang
type BaseUserCamelCase struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"userId"`
    Name  string `json:"userName"`
    Email string `json:"userEmail"`
}
```

and

```golang
type UserWithAddressCamelCase struct {
    BaseUserCamelCase
    Postal string `json:"userPostal"`
    City   string `json:"userCity"`
    Street string `json:"userStreet"`
}
```

My transformation looks like

```golang
var userWithAddressCamelCase UserWithAddressCamelCase

userWithAddressCamelCase.BaseUserCamelCase = BaseUserCamelCase(userWithAddress.BaseUser)
//I can't cast whole userWithAddressCamelCase object to another type because of different field names - BaseUser and BaseUserCamelCase
userWithAddressCamelCase.Name = userWithAddress.Name
userWithAddressCamelCase.Email = userWithAddress.Email
userWithAddressCamelCase.Postal = userWithAddress.Postal
//and so on
```

and I don't like it, because if `BaseUser` or `UserWithAddress` will grow up, I have to add appropriate field to `%CamelCase` structs.

**My question:** is there another more efficient way to handle keys transformation?

Comment: May I just ask _why_? IMO, the same data should be represented consistently across an API, whether it be the request format or the response, it's better to have the same values be represented with the same names. Other than that, I'd probably implement the `Marshaller` interface to do this kind of custom marshalling

Comment: There are no shortcuts in Go. Two structs is the proper approach.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it's for some kind of internal purposes. API is "write only", if I can say so.

Comment: I can add that this transformation is caused by database fields naming, they're in camelCase, and I can't renamed them easily. JSON object is used to save data, and I have to keep keys synced with database fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there another more efficient way to handle keys transformation?

No.

(Well, based on your definition of "efficient". You could use reflection, but I will not recommend this. Your code is perfectly fine. If any struct grows you add a few lines of simple code. There is nothing wrong with simple code which is not going to produce errors and is fast during execution. Just because it doesn't *look* fancy it doesn't mean that there is anything to "improve" here.)

Answer (score 1):

If the need to maintain the field list is what concerns you the most, then I'd suggest making type aliases for your user types and implementing the `json.Marshaler` interface for those aliases, where you'd implement custom JSON encoding. You can even introduce an alternative set of tags and use those there.

Something along these lines:

```golang
type BaseUser struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"user_id" jsonCC:"userId"`
    Name  string `json:"user_name" jsonCC:"userName"`
    Email string `json:"user_email" jsonCC:"userEmail"`
}

type BaseUserCamelCase BaseUser

func (bucc BaseUserCamelCase) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    buccVal := reflect.ValueOf(bucc)
    kvpairs := []string{}

    for i := 0; i < buccVal.NumField(); i++ {
        k := buccVal.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("jsonCC")
        v := buccVal.Field(i).Interface() //TODO: proper JSON encoding of things
        kvpairs = append(kvpairs, fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\":%#v", k, v))
    }

    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", strings.Join(kvpairs, ","))), nil
}
```

Then you can choose marshaling style:

```golang
user := BaseUser{
    ID:    123,
    Name:  "Johnny D03",
    Email: "j@example.com",
}

json.Marshal(user)
// {"user_id":123,"user_name":"Johnny D03","user_email":"j@example.com"}

json.Marshal(BaseUserCamelCase(user))
// {"userId":123,"userName":"Johnny D03","userEmail":"j@example.com"}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know, that `json` tag is hardcoded in the `json` package. So, reflection, anyway